# Creating multi-column page by specifying the content and width of each column

Tags: two-column

After many googling, I found a lot of solutions for the automatic division of the content in multiple columns. For example, [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multiple_columns).

But this is not what I want.

I want to create a multi-column latex side, that *I specify, what will be the width and the content of the various columns*. In the HTML world, I would likely use `<div>`s for the task.

Intuitively, I would like some similar:

```
\begin{multicol}
  \begin{column}[12cm]
     ...content of the left column...
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}[9cm]
     ...content of the right column...
  \end{column}
\end{multicol}
```

Can I somehow do that?

I think using matrices/tables for the task could work, however I experienced many problems with the creation of complex table cells.

Comment: well place two minipages side by side. (If you want page breaks things get more complicated ...)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much! Page break is no problem - I will specify the content with trial & error :-) If you make answers, you will get up + accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting a lot of very useful help in comments, finally I got to this:

```
\noindent\adjustbox{minipage=5cm,valign=t}{
  ...content...
}
\adjustbox{minipage=7cm,valign=t}{
  ...content...
}\adjustbox{minipage=5cm,valign=t}{
  ...content...
}
```

This is a 3-column layout with 5cm-7cm-5cm column widths. All is aligned vertically to the top. The size of the adjustboxes/miniboxes is determined by their content.

In the case of an overlap, I got an unneeded page break and removed overflowing content. So, I need to manually specify the correct content on a trial-error way (which is no problem, this is what I wanted).