# Can I somehow do floating content in Latex?

Tags: overlap

I am trying to make something what would be the analogue of a fixed-positioned `<div>` in the HTML world.

So, I would like to specify the coordinates of a box, and its content. *This content would be rendered into the page independently from all other content, possibly overlapping them.*

I imagine some similar:

```
\begin{overlappingbox}{5cm}{5cm}{10cm}{10cm}
  ...content of the overlapping box...
\end{overlappingbox}
```

Comment: sure, that is what all watermark packages do. Use e.g eso-pic, or textpos, or with a new latex the shipout/foreground hook.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, I check them! Do you have some useful keyword also for my [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/588939/42735)? :-)